# Vertical Scroll is not working in iOS Devices Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

Using hammer.js (v 2.0) I tried to trigger events for the pandown gesture, but when the element Which I am applying the gesture event is having more content than the browser layout height, the default scrolling stops, see this codepen http://codepen.io/shmdhussain/pen/GomRVw#0

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
var myElement1 = document.getElementById('myElement1');
// create a simple instance
// by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

// let the pan gesture support all directions.
// this will block the vertical scrolling on a touch-device while on the element
mc.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

// listen to events...
mc.on("panleft panright panup pandown tap press", function(ev) {
    myElement1.textContent = ev.type +" gesture detected.";
});
```

```css
#myElement {
  background: silver;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 30px/300px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>

<div id="myElement">
  <p id="myElement1">hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
 <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
 <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
 <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
 <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
 <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
 <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
 <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
 <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>
   <p>hekko</p>

</div>
```

Issue happening in iOS Devices iPhone ( tested on iPhone 6Plus with iOS 8.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

vertical scroll:

```
let mc = new Hammer.Manager(element, {
    touchAction: "pan-x"
  });
```

horizontal scroll:

```
let mc = new Hammer.Manager(element, {
            touchAction: "pan-y"
          });
```

check this link:
http://hammerjs.github.io/touch-action/